# Suggested edits are not sent for peer review

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, suggested-edits, posts

Previously for SO, if a person having less than 2K reputations suggested an edit to another person's post, it was displayed at top of the page that the edit is being sent for peer review.

But since yesterday, this message is not displayed and none of the edits are accepted. Does it mean that the editing suggestions are no longer sent for peer review?

**Edit:**
Please note that the suggested edits are not only retagging, but post body editing...

Comment: can you include a link to one such edit?

Comment: Yeah waffles, this is one whom I edited the post body few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619919/how-to-customize-wcf-error-behavior

Comment: @dia: @Jeff approved your edit and it went through: [Suggested Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/66799).  See "Editor Stats" at the bottom of the page.  It reports that you hadn't made another suggested edit since Jun 27.

Comment: Yeah Jeff, the reporting says so.... but have a look at this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593664/htaccess-date-range-help and it has given me +2 in my reputation list... isn t it a conflict?

Comment: You still haven't provided a link to any posts that you've changed the **body** of, rather than just the tags. This problem is not reproducible.

Comment: @ Cody Gray: Here is the link I already mentioned above... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619919/how-to-customize-wcf-error-behavior and this is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620737/converting-microsoft-visualbasic-dateformat ... The thing is that I don t even get the 'Thanks for your edit' message. In the 2nd link, I edited the tags seperately and body text seperately... So earlier, I got 'Thanks for your edit' message in this such cases... I m really confused on this... So sorry if it bothers... I like SO that s why I m actively participating in it...

Comment: @dia: You're a hard-working retagger and editor and your effort is appreciated.  The only explanation seems to be that some of your body edits are simply disappearing.  That's a hard pill to swallow but it might be true.  It's not easy to prove you did something that there is no trace of but I'm inclined to believe you.  Something is not right here.

Comment: @ Rick Sladkey: Thanks a lot and isn t it to be corrected by SO? I hope it s not for me happening that... Thanks again for your response...

Comment: Another user reported nearly this identical problem last week: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96713/edit-to-a-question-got-ignored

Comment: Ok, so this does sound like something other than what I thought it was originally... But I still can't make it happen with a low-rep account. Very strange.

Comment: Hi all, isn t there any solution for this problem??? I still can t edit any post...

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this; when I submit an edit as a 492 rep user, it is indeed placed in the edit suggestion queue for peer review.

Comment: Please note I m not asking about tags, but post body editing... Please see I ve done some post body editing too.. It seems there is some problem in SO with that...

Comment: Very similar issue was posted here last week: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96713/edit-to-a-question-got-ignored

Comment: @ Jeff Atwood: Now the problem seems to be ok... I can see the `Thanks for your edit` message when I suggest an edit... Thanks for your responses